# 'Ruby isn't currently installed' error in RubyMine

Tags: ruby, path, rvm, rubymine

I installed Ruby with RVM on my system, but when I say ruby -v in RubyMine terminal, it says ruby isn't currently installed. But when I type rvm list I can see all Ruby versions installed.

What should I do?

Comment: Try to run: `/bin/bash --login` before `ruby -v`

Comment: Yeah, that solved problem :)

Answer (score 0):

According to creators of Rubymine you have to provide .rvmrc file for the project your creating in rubymine.

Your .rvmrc file will be located at ~/.rvm or /usr/local/rvm

For more information on rvm support using rubymine, check out this link https://www.jetbrains.com/help/ruby/2016.3/rvm-support.html